# Select row if text inside contains a specific text

Tags: android, sqlite

So i have a input called month, and i wanted to make a query so that from all the rows in a custom listview, the rows containing that specific month is returned.
This is my code in my DBAdpater. What must i do so that the db returns all the rows that contain that specific month.
The format that my date is saved is 05/06/15. The string sent in the params is "/08/".

```
public Cursor getRowsFromMonth(String month){
    String[] FROM = { 
            KEY_ROWID,KEY_DATE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_PAIDBY
    };

    String where = "date=?";

    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { 
            "%"+ month+"%"
    };

    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, FROM, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using wildcard character (`%`) then your where clause should use `LIKE` not `=`, instead of

```
String where = "date=?";
```

you need

```
String where = "date LIKE ?";
```

But, I'd also rethink how your date is stored as you may want to use sqlite's date time functions some day:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>
> REAL as Julian
> day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
> 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
>
> INTEGER
> as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
> formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
> time functions.

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Thank you, it worked. i used your code and i also changed the whereclause to "date LIKE ?"